# Set different column colors for each column in excel using Perl

Tags: perl, bash, unix, scripting

My Perl script is generating an excel sheet.

**Output**

```
P   MON #N/A    XML                 xx  ##  c   2   Yes                                         
B   TUE #N/A    TXT                 xx  ##  b   1   No                                          
D   SUN #N/A    EXE                 xx  ##  a   1   No
```

I want the excel sheet's **column** to be highlighted in different colours

I followed this [site](http://search.cpan.org/%7Ejmcnamara/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.37/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel/Examples.pm)

But I am not getting any idea to set different colours for different columns using Perl .

Comment: Would you mind sharing the relevant parts of said Perl script?

Comment: I don't see where this is a duplicate of the linked question. Anyway, look at [Formats in SpreadSheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.37/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm#CELL_FORMATTING), they are what you need.

Comment: @simbabque  The link you posted is of "different text color". I wanted the "background of the cell" to be different. The question is a bit different here.

Comment: @Chronicles: They are all there. Use [set_bg_color](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.37/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm#set_bg_color%28%29). I had a complete code example typed out when the question was closed. You can define a format object for each background-color and assign that when you fill the values in the cells.

Comment: read CPAN examples give you an answer...

Comment: @simbabque Thankx.... set_bg_color and set_fg_color helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `set_column()` method with a format object that has the `bg_color` set. Here is a small working example.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;

my $workbook  = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new( 'columns.xls' );
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();

# Add some formats with background colors.
my $format1   = $workbook->add_format( bg_color => 'yellow' );
my $format2   = $workbook->add_format( bg_color => 0x32 );

# Format column A with a background color of yellow.
$worksheet->set_column('A:A', undef, $format1);

# Format column c with a new width and light green.
$worksheet->set_column('C:C', 30, $format2);


# Add some data to the worksheet.
my $headings = [ 'Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3' ];
my $data = [
    [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ],
    [ 1, 4, 5, 2, 1, 5 ],
    [ 3, 6, 7, 5, 4, 3 ],
];

$worksheet->write( 'A1', $headings );
$worksheet->write( 'A2', $data );

__END__
```

Which gives you output like this:

[image]